# Better OOP practise to add methods to class with relational mapping

Tags: django, factory-boy

Assuming the below sample code structure

```
# Returns a region
class RegionFactory:
      .....

# Returns a user
class UserFactory():
      .....

# Assigns a user with a permission against specific region
class RegionUserPermissionFactory():
      user = UserFactory()
      permission = PermissionFactory()
      ....
```

Now I would like to have a method that allows assigning "user region permission" and I think this method is much suited in the UserFactory because it resembles a real world-class template.

```
 def add_user_domain_permission(permission_options, domain):
     ....
     (Invokes RegionUserPermissionFactory to create objects relevant to
      the user)
     ....
```

Edited 25/09/2019
Is it a better approach to include methods related to RegionUserPermission in the parent class? In my current codebase, there are a few more classes that include user object and is it better OOP practise to add them to UserFactory? Does it violate abstraction encapsulation concepts?

Comment: You want to make a method to add specific permissions to a user, and you are wondering in which of these three classes should this method be, is that right ?
I don't see anything that would be violated by putting it in the UserFactory class, and it does seem logical. However, since you mostly showed pseudo-code, and we don't really know what you want to achieve with the program as a whole, it might be difficult to help you any more than that. I advise giving more information about how your classes work and what you want to do with them so we can help you better.

Comment: Thanks Badda. I will edit the question to include more precise information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of factory_boy is to define factories as relevant to your test cases; the set of attributes and parameters should be defined to provide a simple API when writing tests.
The library focuses on providing *readable and maintainable tests*, rather than adhering strictly to OOP principles ;)

In your example, if some tests require a simple user and others want to attach it to a specific region, you could add a second factory dedicated to that use case, say a `RegionalizedUserFactory`:

```
class RegionalizedUserFactory(UserFactory):
    class Params:
        # Tests would call RegionalizedUserFactory(region_code='xxx')
        # Setting this as a `Param` means that the `region_code` field won't be passed
        # to User.objects.create(...)
        region_code = 'asia'

    add_user_permission = factory.RelatedFactory(
        # Once the `User` is created, call UserPermissionFactory(user=the_user, ...)
        UserPermissionFactory, 'user',

        # And use this factory's region_code attribute as the code for RegionFactory
        permission__region__code=factory.SelfAttribute('....region_code'),
    )
```

This would be used as follows:

```
>>> UserFactory()  # No region perms
<User: John Doe, perms=[]>
>>> RegionalizedUserFactory()   # Default on asia
<User: John Doe, perms=[<Permission: level=admin, region=<Region: asia>>]>
>>> RegionalizedUserFactory(region_code='mars')   # Custom region
<User: John Doe, perms=[<Permission: level=admin, region=<Region: mars>>]>
```

You could also decide to merge both classes in a single declaration, using `factory.Maybe` (which conditionally enables declarations based on other fields):

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    class Params:
        region_code = None

    add_user_permission = factory.Maybe(
        'region_code',
        factory.RelatedFactory(
            UserRegionPermission, 'user',
            permission__region__code=factory.SelfAttribute('....region'),
        ),
    )
```

With that second factory:

```
>>> UserFactory()  # No region_code => no perms
<User: John Doe, perms=[]>
>>> UserFactory(region_code='asia')
<User: John Doe, perms=[<Permission: level=admin, region=<Region: asia>>]>
```

Comment: This is so useful. Thanks Xelnor